# Override default-value for attribute from XSD in derived class

Tags: c#, inheritance, xsd

I have an XSD-file containing some classes as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="NS"/>
  <import namespace="NS" schemaLocation="Reference.xsd"/>
  <element name="Derived" substitutionGroup="lbm:BaseClass" type="lbm:DerivedType"/>
  <complexType name="DerivedType">
    <complexContent>
      <extension base="lbm:BaseClass">
        <sequence>
          ...
        </sequence>
      </extension>
    </complexContent>
  </complexType>
</schema>
```

Where `NS` corresponds the namespace indicated by `lbm`.

Within `Reference.xsd` the class `lbm:BaseClass` is defined as this:

```
<element name="BaseClass" type="lbm:BaseClassType"/>
<complexType name="BaseClassType">
  <complexContent>
    <sequence>
      <element default="270020000" name="ObjektTyp" type="lbm:MyEnum"/>
    </sequence>
  </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

Now what I want to do is to let `Derived` inherit `BaseClass` but with another default-value for `ObjektTyp`. I already tried to override it within derived by adding the appropriate `ObjektTyp`-tag. However when I use xsd.exe to autogenerate the classes on .NET a new property of the same type but with name `ObjektTyp1` is created.

Is there any way I can define another default-value within a derived class for a property defined in a base-class?

```
<element default="270020191" name="ObjektTyp" type="lbm:MyEnum"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example shown, DerivedTyped is derived from lbm:BaseClass by extension:

```
<complexType name="DerivedType">
  <complexContent>
    <extension base="lbm:BaseClass">
      <sequence>
        ...
      </sequence>
    </extension>
  </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

Hence, the declaration

```
<element default="270020191" name="ObjektTyp" type="lbm:MyEnum"/>
```

does not override, but instead creates a new element named ObjectTyp.

Changing the definition of DerivedType to be a derivation by restriction, like so:

```
<complexType name="DerivedType">
  <complexContent>
    <restriction base="lbm:BaseClass">
      <sequence>
        ...
      </sequence>
    </restriction>
  </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

may solve the problem. Note that derivation by restriction has a few constraints, that is, you cannot completely change the layout but only make it more restrictive. Changing the default value is, as far as I know, [allowed](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#derivation-ok-restriction) though.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.example.com"
           xmlns:prefix="http://www.example.com"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:complexType name="test">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="foo" type="xs:string" default="foobar" minOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="test-derived">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:restriction base="prefix:test">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="foo" type="xs:string" default="foobar2" minOccurs="1"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="base" type="prefix:test"/>
    <xs:element name="derived" type="prefix:test-derived"/>
</xs:schema>
```

This is accepted by oXygen and seems to work with Xerces as well as Saxon. With XQuery, I can see the default value correctly set to foobar or foobar2 depending on the element used.

Comment: The problem here I guess is that by defining a default-value in the base-class we already *have* some kind of restriction in the base-class. Defining another default-value is obviosuly not considered "more restrictive" but "not allowed according to the base-class". At least I get some error from XSD-tool "ObjektTyp is not a valid constraint of the base-particle as of Elt:all/Choice/Sequence -- RecurseAsIfGroup" (or something similar, only have german version of the error)

Comment: Hi HimBromBeere, I have added a schema that demonstrates changing the default value and that works on my side. The problem may be elsewhere. I hope it helps!